# Replacing a word begin with @ in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace any word that starts with @ to another word.

Input is **My value is @truth_word and bad**

```
$myword = "My value is @truth_word and bad";
$newtext = preg_replace("/^@/", "good" , $myword); 
echo $newtext; //My value is good and bad;
```

The output should be **My value is good and bad**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a positive lookbehind for either the beginning of the string (`^`) or a white-space character (`\s`) before the `@`, then some number of word characters (`\w`) after it:

```
$myword = "My value is @truth_word and bad";
$newtext = preg_replace("/(?<=^|\s)@\w+/", "good" , $myword); 
echo $newtext;
```

Output

```
My value is good and bad
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/krIZp)